# How to get public properties of a class?

Tags: php, class, properties, public

I can't use simply `get_class_vars()` because I need it to work with PHP version earlier than 5.0.3 (see http://pl.php.net/get_class_vars Changelog)

Alternatively: How can I check if property is public?

Comment: I think this would only be a problem in PHP 5.0.2. In PHP 5.0.1 and earlier, protected and private properties are returned but prefixed with the nul byte (`\x00`) which can be excluded with a regex.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is possible by using reflection.

```
<?php

class Foo {
  public $alpha = 1;
  protected $beta = 2;
  private $gamma = 3;
}

$ref = new ReflectionClass('Foo');
print_r($ref->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC));
```

the result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ReflectionProperty Object
        (
            [name] => alpha
            [class] => Foo
        )

)
```

Answer (score 3):

Or you can do this:

```
$getPublicProperties = create_function('$object', 'return get_object_vars($object);');
var_dump($getPublicProperties($this));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make your class implement the IteratorAggregate interface

```
class Test implements IteratorAggregate
{
    public    PublicVar01 = "Value01";
    public    PublicVar02 = "Value02";
    protected ProtectedVar;
    private   PrivateVar;

    public function getIterator()
    {
        return new ArrayIterator($this);
    }
}


$t = new Test()
foreach ($t as $key => $value)
{
    echo $key." = ".$value."<br>";
}
```

This will output:

```
PublicVar01 = Value01
PublicVar02 = Value02
```